# how to lazy load the children view by default?

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I'm trying to make the view dynamic when using the loadchildren() property

For example, I've got 3 components

**app.html :**

```
Hello App

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home.html :**

```
Hello Home

<a routerLink="./child">My Child</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**child.html :**

```
Hello child
```

I've got 3 routing modules like so :

**app.routing :**

```
Routes = [{
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
}];
```

**home routing :**

```
const routes: Routes = [ {
  path:'',
  component: HomeComponent, 
  children : [{
    path: 'child', 
    loadChildren: () => import('../file/pages/child/child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule)
  }
}];
```

**child.routing :**

```
const routes: Routes = [ {
  path: '',
  component: ChildComponent
}];
```

The problem is that "Hello Home" is waiting for "Hello Child" to completely load before showing on screen.

All I want is, when loading page, showing on screen "Hello Home" without waiting for ChildComponent. Exactly like the "Hello App" do

Comment: Just curious, why 3 routing modules instead of combining everything in one?

Comment: For scalability, avoid to have hundred of link in one file

Comment: Every router is a separate module and every module is lazy loaded. You want to load it directly but I don't think that's possible. Not 100% sure but that's sorta the point of modules.

Comment: I want to recreate a Google Photos or Drive behavior : all the nav, user, header buttons are showing up on screen with the path "mydrive/root" before the nested children files. Just want to make the project scalable, in order to have my default nested child appears after the others stuffs and not having to declare all on app.component.ts ;)